# Creating 32 bit JavaFx Native Bundle in 64 bit machine

Tags: bundle, native, 32bit-64bit, javafx-2, 32-bit

I have my machine and IDE with following configuration

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143)
Java: 1.7.0_07; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.3-b01
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

The JavaFx bundle (.exe) created during build is of 64 bit. My users are in 32 bit machine so I need to create bundles in 32 bit. Is there any way I can create 32 bit exe files using my machine

Tried downloding 32 bit JDK and pointed the same in the project properties but i am not sure if the exe created in 32 bit or not because in task manager the application does not know *32 next to it.

Comment: Unfortunately the jre directory of above 32 bit JDK installation jave 64 bit Java.exe
So Netbeans created 64 bit exe.

I have no idea now how to fix this.

Comment: to generate 32 bit wrapper .exe I set the 32bit Java to be used by netbeans in netbeans.conf but this makes netbeans a bit inefficient in my 64-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

You can by using a 32bit JDK:

```
    <fx:platform basedir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"/>
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me, that where will i find that tag??

Comment: what tag?  <fx:platform?

Comment: Yes i am searching for that tag

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIAEEFCJ